# background positioning drop down menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As it stands i have created a navigation menu using the background-position css property. [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/header.php)

```
    #nav-menu li a{
    background: url("images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 102px;
}

#nav-menu .shop a{
    background-position: left top;
    width: 139px;
}
```

on the shop link i have created a drop-down function to display another menu, the issue i am having is all the  tags within my  property are duplicating the background of

## nav-menu li a

Is there a way i can cancel out this particular background image in my show and hide menu to display another background image?

Comment: your link is broken! give a example in fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace in your css :

```
#nav-menu li a{
background: url("images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
height: 102px;
}
```

With :

```
#nav-menu > li > a{
background: url("images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
height: 102px;
}
```

Know more about Direct Decedent Selector ( " > " ) [**Here**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)

Answer (score 1):

in #nav-menu li a you should use the descendant operator so that only direct children are selected.

For example

```
#nav-menu > li > a
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, is it possible to put an example in Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use first-child; to only set the background to the first element

```
     #nav-menu li:first-child a{
        background: url("images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    }
```

Or you can force the background to something else on all `<li>` elements following another `<li>` element

```
    #nav-menu li + li a{
        background-image: none;
    }
```